# Enter data into TinyDB within an App Inventor app

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, app-inventor

I have got a android app created using **App Inventor**. I have not implemented the use of a `TinyDB`, but I would like to access it manually on my phone to be able to put all the data that I would like my app to search through when running my app.

However the problem I am having is that I cannot find where the `TinyDB` is located within the phone.

I have installed all different types of root browser applications for me to be able to find it but I am not able to find it.

Can someone please tell me another way that I would be able to access the `TinyDB`.

EDIT 2:

I have implemented the `TinyDB` which is storing 3 types of data but on the get value i would like to see whether the student number already exists from a previos run and if it does then it only takes the scanned number if it does not exist then the student number will have to be typed in.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to access it manually on my phone to be able to put all
>   the data that I would like my app to search through when running my
>   app.

It does not make sense, what you are trying to do.

Instead, store your data in a file in csv format (comma separated values) and upload that file as asset into App Inventor. Then read that file on first run of the app using the `file` component, convert it into a list of lists and store that list in `TinyDB` for all further runs of the app.

A very good way to learn App Inventor is to read the free Inventor's Manual here in the AI2 free online eBook   http://www.appinventor.org/book2 ... the links are at the bottom of the Web page.  The book 'teaches' users how to program with AI2 blocks.
There is a free programming course here http://www.appinventor.org/content/CourseInABox/Intro  and the aia files for the projects in the book are here:  http://www.appinventor.org/bookFiles
How to do a lot of basic things with App Inventor are described here:  http://www.appinventor.org/content/howDoYou/eventHandling  .

Also do the tutorials http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/tutorials.html to learn the basics of App Inventor, then try something and follow the
 [Top 5 Tips: How to learn  App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/learn.php)

You will not find a tutorial, which does exactly what you are looking for. But doing the tutorials (not only reading a little bit) help you to understand, how things are working. This is important and this is the first step to do.

Comment: However uploading the CSV file would not work as my data is always changing. And also i have a google spreadsheet bringing the CSV file i would like to be able to download a particular sheet but however i am not able to do this as the data that is downloaded always brings the first sheet as CSV format and therefore does not bring the data from other sheets.

Comment: use a Google fusiontable or a MySQL database to store your data

Comment: I have started to work on firebase recently would you say that this would do the same job as fusion tables and MYSQL database. So far the problem i am having with firebase is that it overwrites data and if a value was blank then all data can easily be deleted from the database. Do you have any tips for using firebase.

Comment: I have shown my coding blocks in the post above under EDIT 2. Bit of guidance on this error would be helpful.

Comment: my tip for you is to use a fusionable to store the data... btw. Stackoverflow is a Question and Answer site, which means you ask 1 question and you get an answer (probably from several people). Stackoverflow is not a site to continue asking completely different questions inside the same question.... btw. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Ok sorry about that. My original question was whether it is possible to access the tinyDB file within the phone and add data manually into it which makes it ready to read into my app.

Comment: the short answer is: No, not possible, because as already said,  it does not make sense to do this

Comment: Is there a limit to the amount of records that a single tinyDB can hold?